# Orthogonal complement of a complex subspace

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $W$ = Span{$(1,i,0), (0,1,-1)$} Find $W^\perp$

If $W$ were not a complex subspace, I would solve this by finding the kernel of the rowspace of the corresponding matrix. However, if I do this on complex vectors, I won't be accounting for conjugates in the Hermitian inner product. So how do I approach this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $u=(1,i,0)$ and $v=(0,1,-1)$; I'll denote by $\langle x,y\rangle$ the inner product.

What you need is a nonzero vector $w$ such that
\begin{cases}
\langle u,w\rangle=0 \\
\langle v,w\rangle=0
\end{cases}

If $w=(x,y,z)$, depending on your definition of inner product, the first equation becomes
$$
1x+\bar{i}y+0z=0
$$
or
$$
1\bar{x}+i\bar{y}+0\bar{z}=0
$$
but they're equivalent, because $\langle y,x\rangle=\overline{\langle x,y\rangle}$.

So the system becomes
$$
\begin{cases}
x-iy=0\\
y-z=0
\end{cases}
$$
which should be easy to solve.

Comment: Aham! Now I see. So, in fact, if we were to do this with a matrix, it would be just like in $\mathbb{R}$, except that we would take the conjugate of the rowspace matrix before finding the kernel.

Comment: @moni94 Yes, that's the same idea

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to augment a basis for $W$ with the standard basis for $\mathbb{C}^3$ and apply Gram-Schmidt. The vectors not in $W$ will form a basis for $W^\perp$.